# How can I get the file path for data shard in the Mapper of a Mapreduce job?

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a mapreduce job, where the file input path is: `/basedirectory/*/*.txt`

Inside the basedirectory, I have different subfolders (CaseA, CaseB etc), each of which contain hdfs text files.

In the map phase of the job, I want to find out where exactly the data shard came from (e.g. CaseA). How can I achieve that?

I've done something similar for mapreduce jobs with more than 1 input hbase tables where I use context.getInputSplit().getTableName() to find the actual table name but not sure what to do for HDFS input files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get input split using `context.getInputSplit()` (where `context` is `mapper.context`) and then use `.getPath()` method on the `inputSplit` to return the file path.